# Compile Error: Expected List Separator or) : error message

Tags: excel, vba

I am receiving "Compile Error: Expected List Separator or)" error message. Can anyone help me with whats causing the error message with the below code.

Only change i made was in the last bracket i replaced "Delta" with "Range("AO294").Text"

```
Sub MyPvt()
'
' MyPvt Macro

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPvt").PivotFields( _
        "[Append1].[Manufacturer].[Manufacturer]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Append1].[Manufacturer].&[Range("AO294").Text]"


End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? Could you add a screenshot of the pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MyPvt()
'
' MyPvt Macro

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPvt").PivotFields( _
        "[Append1].[Manufacturer].[Manufacturer]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Append1].[Manufacturer].[" & Range("AO294").Text & "])"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `.Range.Text`.
Instead try to assign a reference to a range object using `set`. Also you need to close the array.

```
Sub MyPvt1() ' ' MyPvt Macro
Dim arrPivot
Dim pvtValue

pvtValue = Range("AO294").Value

arrPivot = "[Append1].[Manufacturer].&[" & pvtValue & "]"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPvt").PivotFields( _
"[Append1].[Manufacturer].[Manufacturer]").VisibleItemsList = _
Array(arrPivot)

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work. When i tried the code i received Run-Time error:1004 Unable to get the pivot table property of the worksheet class error message. Can you please help.

Comment: That is because you do not have the Pivot Fields in the Pivot Table. I think you should try naming the sheet rather than using "activesheet". So use `Sheets("SHEETNAMEHERE")` instead of `ActiveSheet`, as the above macro will not work if you are in another sheet.

Comment: So check that the active sheet (you should use the correct sheetname instead of active sheet) is actually containing the pivot table.
Afterwards, check if pivot table name is correct (right click the table -> 'Options')

Comment: When i change  ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AO294") with ThisWorkbook.Source.Range("AO294") compile error: method or data member not found error. Source is the name of the sheet. I also double check the pivot tables name. Can you please help.

Comment: It should be `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NAMEOFSHEET")`

Comment: I corrected it now getting runtime error "1004' The query didnt run. Data model cant be acccessed. here is the error message we got. Query (1,30) The syntax for 'Text' is incorrect ([Append1].[Manufacturer].rng.Text]). Can you please help

Comment: still no luck. All i am trying to do is change the pivot table filter based on a combo box selection.

Comment: Sub MyPvt()
'
' MyPvt Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPvt").PivotFields( _
        "[Append1].[Manufacturer].[Manufacturer]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Append1].[Manufacturer].&[3M]")
End Sub This is the original Macro and all i am trying to do is change the 3M with a dynamic cell that pivot table field changes based on the selection on that dynamic cell

Comment: I tried the updated code however getting run time error 1004 Unable to get the pivot tables property of the worksheet class. Following code is highlighted in yellow 
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPvt").PivotFields( _
"[Append1].[Manufacturer].[Manufacturer]").VisibleItemsList = _
Array(arrPivot)

Comment: Are you sure that the previous code worked? What is your sheet name called? Try to remove `.[Manufacturer]` from that line and try again.

Comment: I did remove manufacturer for the line and still not working. The name of the worksheet is Source, the name for the pivot table is MyPvt the range that I want to use to change pivot filter is "AO294", Pivot Field name I'd like to filter is Manufacturer. I hope this help. ANyway I can upload the file so you can take a look at it? Thank you

Comment: Would be easier with the workbook. Can you upload it and will take a look at it later?

Comment: Yes I can. How can I upload it on this site. it doesn't give option to do that in the chat box

Comment: I am not able to edit in the document. Don't know why. But it tells me that you have created it in an older version of Excel.

Comment: Sub FilterPivotTable()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPvt").ManualUpdate = True

   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPvt").PivotFields("Manufacturer").ClearAllFilters

   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPvt").PivotFields("Manufacturer").CurrentPage = _
      Range("AO294").Text

  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPvt").ManualUpdate = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub

Comment: Try this and see if it works for you, otherwise I don't know.

Comment: Unfortunately it still didnt work. Not sure what to do. Its a simple code and i dont understand why i couldnt get it to work. But thank you so much for all your help

Comment: Well are you allowed to manually change the filter for the manufacturer? When I try to change it from all I get a warning message saying that I cannot

Comment: Yes i can manually change the filter for manufacturer. I have Excel 2016 Office 365 Proplus...I wonder if it has anything to do with that?

Comment: i just uploaded the file again see if this one lets you edit it.  https://ufile.io/14212

Comment: I will take a look later. Will be offline for a couple of hours :-)

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for all your help Niclas   
Sub Dropdown ()
'
' Dropdown Macro
'

'
    Sheets("POS Tracker").Select
    Sheets("POS Tracker").Visible = True
    Sheets("Source").Visible = True
    Sheets("Source").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Manufacturer").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Manufacturer").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Manufacturer").CurrentPage = Range("C283").Text
   Sheets("Source").Visible = False
End Sub